# Show that $(x_n, y_n) → (x, y)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $x$ in a Hilbert space $H$ and a sequence
$\{y_n\}$ converges strongly to $y$ in $H$. Show that $(x_n, y_n) → (x, y)$ as $n → ∞$.

Proof idea:

${x_n}$ converges weakly, so $(x_n,a) \rightarrow (x,a)$ for any $a\in H$.

Let $a = y_k\in H$. Then $(x_n,y_k) \rightarrow (x,y_k)$ for any $y_k\in H$.

Does it follow directly that $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,y)$ ?

$\lim\|x_n-y_k\|^2=\|x\|^2-2\lim \langle x_n,y_k \rangle+\|y_k\|^2\leq\|x\|^2-2\liminf \langle x_n,y_k \rangle+\|y_k\|$

$\leq \|x\|^2-2\|x\|\|y_k\|+\|y_k\|^2=\|x-y\|^2$.

Since $\|x\|\leq \liminf\|x_n\|$.

Thanks

Comment: You can't let $a=y_n$, which depends on $n$.

Comment: For each selected $y_n$? Do you mean we should change the index for y?

Comment: That's right. You can say $(x_n, y_m) \to (x, y_m)$.

Comment: I completed this proof by using: Weak convergence is uniformly bounded by some $M$. Then strong convergence implies that $||y_n − y|| \leq \epsilon/ (2M)$. Apply Cauchy-Schwartz on $|<x_n, y_n>-<x, y>|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some estimates for the difference
$$(x_n, y_n) - (x,y)$$

Some calculations:
$$(x_n, y_n) - (x,y) = (x_n, y_n) - (x_n, y) + (x_n, y) - (x,y)$$

Now
$$|(x_n, y_n) - (x_n, y)| = |(x_n, y_n-y) | \le \|x_n\| \cdot \|y_n-y\|$$

The second term $(x_n-x, y)$ clearly approaches $0$. It is the first term that is a bit more delicate.  Here you have to use the fact that a weakly convergent sequence $(x_n)$ is weakly bounded, so bounded ( [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)).  So some heavy machinery is needed, and with that you are done.

Comment: Thanks. I added the skeleton of my proof in my last comment. Some of the details to complete this are in there.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe: No worries!   So it is more subtle than it appears. Also, if you only have weak convergence for $y_n$, the result may not hold. Say $x_n = e_n$, $y_n = e_{n}$, both weakly convergent to $0$, but $(e_n, e_n) = 1$.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe: Also, I would not do double limits, just do the estimate for the difference directly, using that $\|x_n\|\le M$ for some $M>0$. Half of calculus is just properly chosen algebra. Good luck!